# apt-get upgrade failed

Tags: linux, upgrade, apt-get, munin

I have tried to run an "apt-get upgrade" but I get the log below.

It *seems* to have been caused by haveged (I tried to install this via source a while back, and not with apt, there are traces on the system of it, I will attempt to uninstall this using the original source files)

I also have munin-node (pretty sure this was via apt), I stopped the service so I don't think it's this causing the issue?

```
Setting up exim4-base (4.72-6+squeeze3) ...
insserv: warning: script 'K02ossec' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: warning: script 'ossec' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: warning: script 'haveged' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: There is a loop between service munin-node and haveged if stopped
insserv:  loop involving service haveged at depth 2
insserv:  loop involving service munin-node at depth 1
insserv: Stopping haveged depends on munin-node and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: exiting now without changing boot order!
update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header
dpkg: error processing exim4-base (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
configured to not write apport reports
                                      dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of exim4-daemon-light:
 exim4-daemon-light depends on exim4-base (>= 4.72); however:
  Package exim4-base is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing exim4-daemon-light (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of exim4:
 exim4 depends on exim4-base (>= 4.72); however:
  Package exim4-base is not configured yet.
 exim4 depends on exim4-daemon-light | exim4-daemon-heavy | exim4-daemon-custom; however:
  Package exim4-daemon-light is not configured yet.
  Package exim4-daemon-heavy is not installed.
  Package exim4-daemon-custom is not installed.
dpkg: error processing exim4 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up apache2.2-common (2.2.16-6+squeeze10) ...
configured to not write apport reports
                                      configured to not write apport reports
                                                                            insserv: warning: script 'K02ossec' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: warning: script 'ossec' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: warning: script 'haveged' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: There is a loop between service munin-node and haveged if stopped
insserv:  loop involving service haveged at depth 2
insserv:  loop involving service munin-node at depth 1
insserv: Stopping haveged depends on munin-node and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: exiting now without changing boot order!
update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header
dpkg: error processing apache2.2-common (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
configured to not write apport reports
                                      dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of apache2-mpm-prefork:
 apache2-mpm-prefork depends on apache2.2-common (= 2.2.16-6+squeeze10); however:
  Package apache2.2-common is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing apache2-mpm-prefork (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
configured to not write apport reports
                                      dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of apache2:
 apache2 depends on apache2-mpm-worker (= 2.2.16-6+squeeze10) | apache2-mpm-prefork (= 2.2.16-6+squeeze10) | apache2-mpm-event (= 2.2.16-6+squeeze10) | apache2-mpm-itk (= 2.2.16-6+squeeze10); however:
  Package apache2-mpm-worker is not installed.
  Package apache2-mpm-prefork is not configured yet.
  Package apache2-mpm-event is not installed.
  Package apache2-mpm-itk is not installed.
 apache2 depends on apache2.2-common (= 2.2.16-6+squeeze10); however:
  Package apache2.2-common is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing apache2 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up clamav-freshclam (0.97.6+dfsg-1~squeeze1) ...
configured to not write apport reports
                                      insserv: warning: script 'K02ossec' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: warning: script 'ossec' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: warning: script 'haveged' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: There is a loop between service munin-node and haveged if stopped
insserv:  loop involving service haveged at depth 2
insserv:  loop involving service munin-node at depth 1
insserv: Stopping haveged depends on munin-node and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: exiting now without changing boot order!
update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header
dpkg: error processing clamav-freshclam (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
configured to not write apport reports
                                      dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of clamav:
 clamav depends on clamav-freshclam | clamav-data; however:
  Package clamav-freshclam is not configured yet.
  Package clamav-data is not installed.
  Package clamav-freshclam which provides clamav-data is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing clamav (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libapache2-mod-php5:
 libapache2-mod-php5 depends on apache2-mpm-prefork (>> 2.0.52) | apache2-mpm-itk; however:
  Package apache2-mpm-prefork is not configured yet.
  Package apache2-mpm-itk is not installed.
 libapache2-mod-php5 depends on apache2.2-common; however:
  Package apache2.2-common is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing libapache2-mod-php5 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
configured to not write apport reports
                                      configured to not write apport reports
                                                                            Errors were encountered while processing:
 exim4-base
 exim4-daemon-light
 exim4
 apache2.2-common
 apache2-mpm-prefork
 apache2
 clamav-freshclam
 clamav
 libapache2-mod-php5
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Have you tried `apt-get install -f`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't able to stop haveged without an error being thrown.

I also moved to using [checkinstall](http://asic-linux.com.mx/~izto/checkinstall/) when installing things from source, it will package up all of the files into a package and will install it that way, which makes it easier to remove all associated files.

I removed all the files that the source version of haveged used, but I think the main culprit was **/etc/init.d/haveged**

Then "sudo apt-get upgrade" worked with no problems